# Counting and grouping challenge in a pivot table with T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a pivot table that converts a vertical database design to a horizontal one:

The source table:

```
Id  ParentId    Property    Value
---------------------------------
1   1           Date        01-09-2015
2   1           CountValue  2
3   1           TypeA       Value1
4   1           TypeB       Value2
5   1           TypeC       Value2
6   2           Date        15-10-2015
7   2           CountValue  3
8   2           TypeA       Value3
9   2           TypeB       Value22
10  2           TypeC       Value99
```

After pivoting this looks like:

```
ParentId    Date        CountValue  TypeA   TypeB   TypeC
----------------------------------------------------------
1           01-09-2015  2           Value1  Value2  Value2
2           15-10-2015  3           Value3  Value22 Value99
```

Then, there's a look-up table for valid values in columns `TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC`:

```
Id  Name    Value
-----------------
1   TypeA   Value1
2   TypeA   Value2
3   TypeA   Value3
4   TypeB   Value20
5   TypeB   Value21
6   TypeB   Value22
7   TypeC   Value1
8   TypeC   Value2
```

So, given the above structure I'm looking for a way to query the pivot table in a way that I'll get a count of all invalid values in `TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC` where `Date` is a valid date and `CountValue` is not empty and greater than 0.

How can I achieve a result that is expected and outputted like below:

```
Count   Column
--------------
0       TypeA
1       TypeB
1       TypeC
```

I've accomplished the result by creating three several queries and glue the results using UNION, but I think it should also be possible using the pivot table, but I'm unsure how. Can the desired result be realized using the pivot table?

Note: the database used is a SQL Server 2005 database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not approach this a PIVOT, otherwise you have to pivot your data, then unpivot it to get the output required. Breaking it down step by step you can get your valid parent IDs using this:

```
SELECT  t.ParentID
FROM    #T AS t
GROUP BY t.ParentID
HAVING  ISDATE(MAX(CASE WHEN t.Property = 'Date' THEN t.Value END)) = 1 
AND     MAX(CASE WHEN t.Property = 'CountValue' THEN CONVERT(INT, t.Value) END) > 0;
```

The two having clauses limit this to your criteria of having a valid date, and a CountValue that is greater than 0

The next step would be to find your invalid properties:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    #T AS t
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    #V AS v
            WHERE   v.Name = t.Property
            AND     v.Value = t.Value
        );
```

This will include Date, and CountValue, and also won't include `TypeA` because all the properties are valid, so a bit more work is required, we must find the distinct properties we are interested in:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Name 
FROM    #V
```

Now we can combine this with the invalid properties to get the count, and with the valid parent IDs to get the desired result:

```
WITH ValidParents AS
(   SELECT  t.ParentID
    FROM    #T AS t
    GROUP BY t.ParentID
    HAVING  ISDATE(MAX(CASE WHEN t.Property = 'Date' THEN t.Value END)) = 1 
    AND     MAX(CASE WHEN t.Property = 'CountValue' THEN CONVERT(INT, t.Value) END) > 0
), InvalidProperties AS
(   SELECT  t.Property
    FROM    #T AS t
    WHERE   t.ParentID IN (SELECT vp.ParentID FROM ValidParents AS vp)
    AND     NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    #V AS v
                WHERE   v.Name = t.Property
                AND     v.Value = t.Value
            )
)
SELECT  [Count] =  COUNT(t.Property), 
        [Column] = v.Name
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM #V) AS V
        LEFT JOIN InvalidProperties AS t
            ON t.Property = v.Name
GROUP BY v.Name;
```

Which gives:

```
Count   Column
--------------
0       TypeA
1       TypeB
1       TypeC
```

**SCHEMA FOR ABOVE QUERIES**

*For SQL Server 2008+. Apologies, I don't have SQL Server 2005 anymore, and forgot it doesn't support table value constructors.*

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Id INT, ParentId INT, Property VARCHAR(10), Value VARCHAR(10));
INSERT #T (Id, ParentId, Property, Value)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Date', '01-09-2015'), (2, 1, 'CountValue', '2'), (3, 1, 'TypeA', 'Value1'),
    (4, 1, 'TypeB', 'Value2'), (5, 1, 'TypeC', 'Value2'), (6, 2, 'Date', '15-10-2015'),
    (7, 2, 'CountValue', '3'), (8, 2, 'TypeA', 'Value3'), (9, 2, 'TypeB', 'Value22'),
    (10, 2, 'TypeC', 'Value99');

CREATE TABLE #V (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(5), Value VARCHAR(7));    
INSERT #V (Id, Name, Value)
VALUES
    (1, 'TypeA', 'Value1'), (2, 'TypeA', 'Value2'), (3, 'TypeA', 'Value3'), 
    (4, 'TypeB', 'Value20'), (5, 'TypeB', 'Value21'), (6, 'TypeB', 'Value22'), 
    (7, 'TypeC', 'Value1'), (8, 'TypeC', 'Value2');
```

Comment: This is taking me some time to figure out how it exactly works. Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I've converted the sample names to my real situation (the vertical table contains over 1.300 unique "Property" items). I do believe the PIVOT table was not the right way to solve it in the end, but I started from there in order to get the table rotated. Thanks, +1 and accepted for also taking the Date and CountValue criteria into account.

Answer (score 1):

Final result without `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT [count] = SUM(CASE WHEN l.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ,t.Property
FROM #lookup l
RIGHT JOIN #tab t  
  ON t.Property = l.Name
  AND t.Value = l.Value
WHERE t.Property LIKE 'Type%'
GROUP BY t.Property;
```

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372816)**

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(
   Id       INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,ParentId INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Property VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,Value    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (1,1,'Date','01-09-2015');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (2,1,'CountValue','2');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (3,1,'TypeA','Value1');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (4,1,'TypeB','Value2');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (5,1,'TypeC','Value2');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (6,2,'Date','15-10-2015');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (7,2,'CountValue','3');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (8,2,'TypeA','Value3');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (9,2,'TypeB','Value22');
INSERT INTO #tab(Id,ParentId,Property,Value) VALUES (10,2,'TypeC','Value99');

CREATE TABLE #lookup(
   Id    INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Name  VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,Value VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (1,'TypeA','Value1');
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (2,'TypeA','Value2');
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (3,'TypeA','Value3');
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (4,'TypeB','Value20');
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (5,'TypeB','Value21');
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (6,'TypeB','Value22');
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (7,'TypeC','Value1');
INSERT INTO #lookup(Id,Name,Value) VALUES (8,'TypeC','Value2');
```

**EDIT:**

Adding more criteria:

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372844)**

```
SELECT [count] = SUM(CASE WHEN l.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      ,t.Property
FROM #lookup l
RIGHT JOIN #tab t  
  ON t.Property = l.Name
  AND t.Value = l.Value
WHERE t.Property LIKE 'Type%'
  AND t.ParentId IN (SELECT ParentId FROM #tab WHERE Property = 'Date' AND ISDATE(VALUE) = 1)
  AND t.ParentID IN (SELECT ParentId FROM #tab WHERE Property = 'CountValue' AND Value > 0)
GROUP BY t.Property;
```

Comment: I like the way how simple this is solved. Only two things weren't taken into account; having a valid date and assuring CountValue is greater than 0. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Ben Could you provide data that break my code? I will try to improve it. About `DATE` you should validate it before you insert to DB. Unfortunately with SQL Server 2005 there is no fancy methods as `TRY_PARSE`.

Comment: I'm not sure it would break; but the two criteria are mandatory in order to get the right result. TRY_PARSE support would be neat since I often come accross invalid data that throws an error in the query execution. For example; dates are stored as text (due to the vertical design) but aren't always a valid date... I know; not a perfect design, but it's the design that exists and I have to work with.

Comment: That's an excellent answer as well. Unfortunately I can't accept multiple answers or give more +1's. Thanks for sharing your knowlegde :)

Comment: @Ben This is no problem. Happy I can help.